# Background watermark color

Tags: backgrounds, watermark

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents= text, opacity=0.1,color=grey}              % error for grey
\usepackage{everypage}
\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

I am using watermark in my document. But using grey colour yields the error `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color grey'. ...{\numberline {1.12}Boolean polynomial}{53}`.

May be the default color is 80% grey? But if I use `\backgroundsetup{contents= text, opacity=0.1}`, then it becomes red.

Comment: Try `gray` rather than `grey`.

Comment: Can you try `gray`?

Comment: `gray` works...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in the comments.